# Ubuntu virtual machine on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I've got ubuntu install on virtual machine with vmware player.

I'm deploying a web app on this virtual machine and it's unreachable from outside my computer.

When I check IP with `ifconfig eth0` on the virtual machine I can access the web app from the host machine but not from others in network.

I've googled and found nothing really useful which led me here. 
Can someone suggest further course of action?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your network interface to Bridged mode, then the other computers on the LAN will be able to access your VM.